# How to create powershell cmdlet (C#) output parameters

Tags: c#, powershell

There are several examples in the common parameters, like ErrorVariable, InformationVariable;

```
get-item foad: -ev foo
$foo
```

"get-item" will create and set the value for $foo to an instance of ErrorRecord.
How can I create my own parameters that do something similar?

Basically, I'm creating a cmdlet that uses WriteObject() to write data to the pipeline, but then I also have some additional information that I want to allow users to access - essentially out of band data - that isn't part of the pipeline.

An example of an out parameter in C#:

```
public class ExampleCode
{
    public int GetMyStuff(int param1, out string someVar)
    {
        someVar = "My out-of-band result";
        return param1 + 1;
    }

    public static void RunMe()
    {
        ExampleCode ex = new ExampleCode();
        string value;
        int result = ex.GetMyStuff(41, out value);

        Console.WriteLine($"result is {result}, OOB Data is {value}");
    }
}
```

I'm looking for how to convert "GetMyStuff()" into a powershell cmdlet.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "MyStuff")]
public class ExampleCmdLet : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = false)] int param1;
    [Parameter(Mandatory = false)] string someVar; // How to make this [out] ?
    protected override void ProcessRecord()            
    {
        someVar = "My out-of-band result";
        WriteObject(param1 + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to set a *PowerShell* variable, not a .NET variable.

Accessing PowerShell variables requires accessing them via the caller's *session state*.

In [`System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet)-derived cmdlets you can set variables via `this.SessionState.PSVariable.Set(<varName>, <value>)`:

```bash
# Compile a Get-MyStuff cmdlet and import it into the current session.
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Management.Automation;

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "MyStuff")]
public class ExampleCmdLet : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter()] public int Param1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter()] public string SomeVar { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {

        // Assign to the $SomeVar variable in the caller's context.
        this.SessionState.PSVariable.Set(SomeVar, 42);

        WriteObject(Param1 + 1);
    }

}
'@ -PassThru | % Assembly | Import-Module                                                                           #'

# Call Get-MyStuff and pass the *name* of the 
# variable to assign to, "targetVariable", which sets
# $targetVariable:
Get-MyStuff -Param1 666 -SomeVar targetVariable
# Output the value of $targetVariable
$targetVariable
```

The above yields:

```bash
667  # Output from the cmdlet, via WriteObject()
42   # Value of $targetVariable, set by Get-MyStuff
```

Comment: To expand on this answer - accepting a string variable name is the canonical way to do this in PowerShell - e.g. `Tee-Object -Variable MyVar` creates `$MyVar`, or the automatic `ErrorVariable` parameter on all cmdlets. If you're nice, you'll support the `+` prefix to append to an existing ArrayList. An alternate way to do it is to accept a parameter of type `[ref]`, but that's not very powershelly.